# no proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'cucumber.options'

Tags: java, cucumber

Hi I'm recieiving this error message no proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'cucumber.options'

I've got all of the neccesary jars and referenced them in the project.

```
        package Cucumber;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @Cucumber.Options(
            format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
            features = {"src/cucumber/"}
            )
    public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

I'm a bit stumped, im also following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD4B839qfos

I'm a bit stumped on how to resolve it as far as I can see I've word for word followed it up to this point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
package Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/"}
        )
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```